# Is there a past tense conjugation form for ば？

Tags: conjugations, conjunctions

I have been looking at conjunctive forms of verbs and my grammar books shows me a negative and affirmative version of ば　but what about a past tense and a past tense negative?

Would they be `じゃなてれば` and `くなかてれば`?

Comment: I haven't gotten this far in exploring なら、でも what i am assuming is that acts the same way as ば　it is just the past tense form. So it would be a sentence something like
Since they didn't go to the store, we have now food.

Comment: 'Since they didn't go to the store, we have now food'???

Comment: @Chocolate I think they meant "we have no food" and the w is a typo.

Comment: We don't use なら/ば etc. to say 'Since they didn't go to the store, we have no food.' It'd be like 「買い物に/店に行かなかった'ので'/'から'、食料/食べるもの/食べ物がない。」.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The past tense is shown by た, and its ば form should be たらば. However, "ば" is usually omitted in this case, so normally "たら" is used by itself without "ば".

E.g. 雨が降っ**たら**中止だ。 If it rained the (event) will be cancelled.

The negative for past tense is なかった (E.g. 降ら**なかった**), formed by ない + た, so its ば form should follow the rule for た to be なかったら. Again ば is omitted.

E.g. 私が行か**なかったら**、がっかりしますよね。 If I don't go, (he) would be disappointed.

Comment: You mean...たらば is also acceptable?

Comment: Actually I've never seen it ....

Comment: @fefe-san, Ah, OK. lol...

Answer (score 5):

Recall that `ば` (-eba) attaches to a verb, and past tense affix turns a verb into something other than a verb. That means you cannot directly attach `ば` to past tense. You need to insert `なら` or `ら` in between the past tense and `ば`. In that case, `ば` can be omitted.

> ...た(な)ら(ば)

Answer (score 5):

- the present tense affirmative:

  > 「走れば」, 「走るならば」, 「走るのならば」（＝「走るなら」, 「走るのなら」）
- the present tense negative:

  > 「走らなければ」, 「走らないならば」, 「走らないのであれば」 （＝「走らないなら」, 「走らないのなら」）
- the past tense affirmative:

  > 「走ったならば」 （＝「走ったら」, 「走ったなら」, 「走っていたら」）
- the past tense negative:

  > 「走らなかったならば」, but I think 「走らなかったら」, 「走っていなかったら」 would be more natural.

Oops, I was off the point?

Comment: @cypher san... thank you again! Ahh I feel so bad...

Comment: No, it's OK :) I've tried to rewrite various sections of the [editing guide](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/625) BTW as I thought some of my explanations etc could've been better written. 時間があったらのぞいてみてね、あはは^^